# Can you mutate onChange globally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, dplyr

### Is it possible to mutate the HTML 'onChange' globally?

for example, could I make it so that onChange always dispatches (redux dispatch) the return value of every event handler?

Yes, I'm aware this may be the most evil thing you could do. I'm trying to understand how event handlers are implemented at a language level.

It would be interesting to know how this impacts frameworks, IE React, but this question is itself focused on the browser/DOM. In this case the "real" onChange.

Example

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript>

//is there anything we can do here to make the onchange below
//do something with the 5 it returns?

//for example, maybe console.log it, or redux dispatch it?

</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" onChange="function(event){return 5;}" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you talking about HTML's `onchange` attribute or React's `onChange`? React's is read by React and changed to an `addEventListener` call.

Comment: Good clarifying question! Editing now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by mutating the addEventListener function inside the EventTarget propotype. consider the following example:

```js
const oldAddEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(eventName, eventHandler, useCapture) {
  const modifiedEventHandler = function(event) {
    if (event.type === 'change') {
      //dispatch your action here
      store.dispatch(....);
    }
    eventHandler(event);
  };
  oldAddEventListener.call(this, eventName, modifiedEventHandler, useCapture);
}
```

If the event type is 'change' it will first run the custom code you have in the `if (event.type === 'change') {...}` block and continue with the normal flow, calling the event handler function. Or else, it will just call the event handler function in the normal flow.

I do not recommend mutating EventTarget prototype in a serious project as it can lead to unforeseen issues, especially when you use third party scripts. But for educational purposes, I recommend playing around with prototypes and mutating the original behavior of javascript, as it helps you understand javascript better. Plus, Prototypes are fun! =)